# Jxls - Transformer class is org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer

Tags: java, jxls

I'm working on exporting the results of a `Java` program to an `excel` sheet. I'm using `Jxls` for this.
It works when I use `XLSTransforme`r, but the calculation of the excel template are not performed. To have these calulations performed, I then try to use the `Transformer class`, but I got a debug message : `DEBUG org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory - Transformer class is org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer` , while my imports are the same as  in the examples on `Jxls` sourceforge page.

```
private void exportData(File file) throws ParseException, IOException {

    AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder();

    int o = 0;
    List<ListData2> rs2 = new ArrayList<ListData2>();
    ListData2 s2 = new ListData2(item[o], rep[o], justefaux[o], tempsrep[o]);
    for(int i=0; i<tableau.getRowCount(); i++){
        item[i]=((DataIdGenre) tableau.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
        rep[i]=((DataIdGenre) tableau.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
        justefaux[i]=((DataIdGenre) tableau.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 4).toString();
        tempsrep[i]=((DataIdGenre) tableau.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 5).toString();
        ListData2 temp = new ListData2(item[i], rep[i], justefaux[i], tempsrep[i]);
        s2.add(temp);
        rs2.add(s2);
    }



    InputStream in = IdGenre.class.getResourceAsStream("/xlsTemplates/IdGenre/IdGenreTemplate.xlsx");
 try
    {OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("d:/IdGenre.xlsx");

     Context context = new Context();
     context.putVar("rs2", rs2);

     Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.createTransformer(in, out);
     JexlExpressionEvaluator evaluator = (JexlExpressionEvaluator) transformer.getTransformationConfig().getExpressionEvaluator();
     Map<String, Object> functionMap = new HashMap<>();
     functionMap.put("joiner", new ListUtil());
     evaluator.getJexlEngine().setFunctions(functionMap);

     areaBuilder.setTransformer(transformer);
     List xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
     Iterator iterator = xlsAreaList.iterator();

     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
         Area xlsArea = (Area) iterator.next();
         xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef(xlsArea.getStartCellRef().getCellName()), context);
     }
     transformer.write();

    }
    finally
    {
        in.close();
    }
}


public static class ListUtil {

    public String join(List list) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Object o : list) {
            if (builder.length() != 0) {
                builder.append(" / ");
            }
            builder.append(o);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Stack trace :

```
15:44:44.975 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory - Transformer class is org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(Unknown Source)
at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(Unknown Source)
...
```

I got the same stack trace when I try with the JxlsHelper class :

```
private void exportData(File file) throws ParseException, IOException {

    int o = 0;
    List<ListData2> rs2 = new ArrayList<ListData2>();
    ListData2 s2 = new ListData2(item[o], rep[o], justefaux[o], tempsrep[o]);
    for(int i=0; i<tableau.getRowCount(); i++){
        item[i]=((DataIdGenre) tableau.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
        rep[i]=((DataIdGenre) tableau.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
        justefaux[i]=((DataIdGenre) tableau.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 4).toString();
        tempsrep[i]=((DataIdGenre) tableau.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 5).toString();
        ListData2 temp = new ListData2(item[i], rep[i], justefaux[i], tempsrep[i]);
        s2.add(temp);
        rs2.add(s2);
    }



    InputStream in = IdGenre.class.getResourceAsStream("/xlsTemplates/IdGenre/IdGenreTemplate.xlsx");
 try
    {OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("d:/IdGenreYOLO.xlsx");

     Context context = new Context();
     context.putVar("rs2", rs2);
     JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(in, out, context);

    }
    finally
    {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug message you get

```
15:44:44.975 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory - Transformer class is org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer
```

is just an information message indicating that Jxls PoiTransformer will be used to produce an Excel output.

The real error has nothing to do with Jxls but is connected with the NullPointerException you are having next

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(Unknown Source)
at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(Unknown Source)
...
```

So you should look further into the stacktrace and see why do you get NullPointerException at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics()

**Update:**

If you have a problem with Excel not calculating formulas you can use techniques explained at [POI Formula Evaluation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html). For example you can force Excel to recalculate formulas using `workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true)` after Jxls processing is done. 
You can get a workbook instance by calling [PoiTransformer](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/javadoc/jxls-poi/org/jxls/transform/poi/PoiTransformer.html#getWorkbook--)`getWorkbook()` method.

Comment: Great, thanks. The `NullPointerException` originates from a `JFileChooser`. However, the situation remains, as my excel sheet is unpopulated with the different codes above. It works like a charm with `XLSTransformer`, but the excel cells have to be revalidated to activate the formulas. Is there a way to process them with `XLSTransformer` ?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an information on formulas evaluation

Comment: Nice. Do you an idea for my other question about having different maps for different sheets with `XLSTransformer` ?

Comment: Not sure I understood the problem. You should probably create a new question or post to jxls user group explaining in details what is not working and attach the example excel files.

Comment: I've edited the question with more details : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181932/maps-and-jxls-process-different-excel-sheets-separately-with-xlstransformer)